# How do I add error bars on a histogram?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, errorbar

I've created a histogram to see the number of similar values in a list.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("Pendel-Messung.dat")
stdm = (np.std(data))/((700)**(1/2))
breite = 700**(1/2)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.set_ylim(0,150)
ax1.hist(data, bins=breite)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(0,150/700)

plt.show()
```

I want to create error bars (the error being stdm) in the middle of each bar of the histogram. I know I can create errorbars using

```
plt.errorbar("something", data, yerr = stdm)
```

But how do I make them start in the middle of each bar? I thought of just adding breite/2, but that gives me an error.

Sorry, I'm a beginner! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ax.hist` returns the bin edges and the frequencies (`n`) so we can use those for `x` and `y` in the call to `errorbar`. Also, the `bins` input to `hist` takes either an integer for the number of bins, or a sequence of bin edges. I think you we trying to give a bin width of `breite`? If so, this should work (you just need to select an appropriate `xmax`):

```
n,bin_edges,patches = ax.hist(data,bins=np.arange(0,xmax,breite))

x = bin_edges[:-1]+breite/2.

ax.errorbar(x,n,yerr=stdm,linestyle='None')
```